# Meaning of 'glass that's with canary lined'?

Tags: expressions, phrase-meaning, poetic

The 17th-century poet Alexander Brome wrote a poem called *The Resolve* (anthologised in the *Oxford Book of English verse*.  What is the meaning of the phrase 'with Canary lined' in last line of the poem below? I can't tell if it's meant to be canary (bird), Canary as an area in London, or some other reference I'm missing—nothing seems to make sense as something lining a glass....

> TELL me not of a face that's fair,
>    Nor lip and cheek that's red,
> Nor of the tresses of her hair,
>     Nor curls in order laid,
> Nor of a rare seraphic voice
>     That like an angel sings;
> Though if I were to take my choice
>     I would have all these things:
> But if that thou wilt have me love,
>     And it must be a she,
> The only argument can move
>     Is that she will love me.
>
> The glories of your ladies be
>     But metaphors of things,
> And but resemble what we see
>     Each common object brings.
> Roses out-red their lips and cheeks,
>    Lilies their whiteness stain;
> What fool is he that shadows seeks
>     And may the substance gain?
> Then if thou'lt have me love a lass,
>     Let it be one that's kind:
> Else I'm a servant to the glass
>     That's with Canary lined.

Comment: Hello, poetryreader312. Some dictionaries give the relevant sense (eg [Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/canary)) while others (eg [Cambridge Dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/canary)) probably consider it too rarely used nowadays to list.

Answer (score 35):

*Canary* refers to **Canary wine,**

> A sweet fortified white wine produced in the Canary Islands; a variety of this (now historical). Later also more generally: any wine produced in the Canary Islands.
>
> — OED

and *lining the glass* simply means that the glass contains it.

If the poet doesn't get to love a kind lass, then he will be driven to drink.

---

Note that London's Canary Wharf is so named because [that's where goods from the Canary Islands were landed](https://www.canarydevelopment.com/why-is-it-called-canary-wharf/).

Comment: Canary wine was a type of wine known as [sack](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sack_(wine)) probably similar to sweet (or sweetened) sherry.

Comment: Discussion about the use of the verb *were landed* has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/138196/discussion-on-answer-by-andrew-leach-meaning-of-glass-thats-with-canary-lined). Please continue any discussion there.

Comment: Worth noting that the birds are also named after the islands.

Comment: Hm, I guess verse like this is the reason Alexander Brome is so well-known today.

Comment: @StuartF:  The island of [Madeira](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Madeira) is not too far from the Canary Islands and gave its name to another [fortified wine](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Madeira_wine) that is more familiar to us today.  It wouldn't surprise me if the two were similar.

Answer (score 1):

I agree with Andrew's answer in that Canary refers to Canary Wine, but I don't think that the overall meaning of '*glass with canary lined*' is suggesting the narrator would be driven to drink.

Rather, I think it's continuing the point in the rest of the stanza: that by focusing on physical attributes rather than love, people are seeking "shadows" over "substance".

So, "*Else I'm a servant to the glass / That's with Canary lined*", is suggesting that in a relationship without kindness, he would be limited to appreciating a woman's physical form (the glass), rather than the love that is of true value contained within (the wine)